# Use svcutil for generating C# Classes from simple xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have following XML. I am trying to generate C# Classes using svcutil. I understand that there are other tools (like Visual Studio Paste Special and [XML2CSharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net)) – but I need to see how svcutil is generating it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" templateId="2.16.840.1.113883.3.27.1776">
    <title>Gc test Consultation Note</title>
    <effectiveTime value="20000407"/>
    <component>
        <StructuredBody>
            <component>
                <section>
                    <code code="10164-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
                    <title>History of Present Illness</title>
                    <text>Test patient is a 67 year old male referred for further asthma management. Onset of asthma in his 
                <content revised="delete">twenties</content>
                <content revised="insert">teens</content>.
                He was hospitalized twice last year, and already twice this year. He has not been able to be weaned off steroids for the past several months. 
                        </text>
                </section>
            </component>
        </StructuredBody>
    </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

I used svcutil articles and used following command – but it gave a warning saying that no code is generated.

```
   svcutil.exe /target:code /dataContractOnly /serializer:XmlSerializer /importXmlTypes /collectionType:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 hl7sample.xml
```

[image]

What can done to generate C# Classes from this XML using svcutil?

Comment: `svcutil` produces classes based on a SOAP service contract (or, at the very least, an XML schema). What you've got there is plain old XML, not SOAP. `svcutil` doesn't generate classes for that. If you need to see "how `svcutil` is generating it" because this is part of a service, you'll need to give it at least the schema of `ClinicalDocument`, not an actual `ClinicalDocument`.

Comment: Try the `xsd.exe` first to generate the XSD from your XML. Only then run `svcutil` on the XSD to have client classes.

Comment: @WiktorZychla XSD.exe fails to generate xsd for this. Did you try?

Comment: XSD.exe burps because you have <component><StructuredBody><component>stuff</component></StructuredBody></component>.  It appears that the XSD.exe tool doesn't like having identically named elements nested inside themselves.  If it were me, I'd manually rename one of the component elements, run the tool, and then go back and muck with the generated XSD (renaming it back).  You may find that it's difficult (who knows maybe even impossible) to describe that in XML Schema.  By the way, it might have been nice for you to post the XSD.exe error message - I don't have any characters left.